# jQuery media query that works on both resize AND load?

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a responsive site, and I am trying to run certain jQuery functions only when the screen is at or below 480px wide. I can only get it to partially work. If you load the page with your browser < 480px wide, it works. But if you load the page > 480px wide, and then resize it to <480, it doesn't work. I need it to work in both circumstances, turning off and on as you resize accordingly. What am I doing wrong? Here is what I have that works only if you load the page at <=480.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    if ( $("div#wrapper").css("overflow") === "visible") {      
    // mobile js goes here
}
});
```

I have also tried it this way, but once I resize it starts looping everything I put in the "mobile js goes here" part and crashes the browser???

```
$(window).resize(function(){    
    if ( $("div#wrapper").css("overflow") === "visible") {
        // mobile js goes here
    }
});
```

*** UPDATE *** 
Ok, based on the two answers below, I tried to do a hybrid of both answers. I understand that to achieve what I want, I have to remove all the code I add to the <480 if it's >480. But since I have about 10 functions, that seems pretty inefficient to have to remove each one individually. So instead, I tried to use window).resize to simply add and remove a class of "mobile" to the body tag. And then use a conditional that "if the body has a class of mobile, do this...." where I will include my 10 functions. However, that only partially works too. The adding/removing of the class works. But the rest of it only works if you first load the page at <480. Here is a fiddle of what I have so far. Is there a way to make this work?

http://jsfiddle.net/UAkHz/59/

Comment: please check my answer I made it easier way

Comment: I updated my question with where I am now. Is there a way to make my fiddle work? http://jsfiddle.net/UAkHz/59/

Comment: your fiddle is working.

Comment: No, it only appends the "test" div if you load the page at less than 480px wide. If you load the page >480, the test div doesn't append. I'm trying to avoid having to undo all of my code in an "else" statement, but it looks like I have no choice?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/UAkHz/66/ please check this. this is the thing you want?

Comment: Thanks @codinfreak. This works, but it's still the same issue -- I'll have to remove each individual function I add, one by one. It looks like that's just the way it has to be. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the code as a resize handler and then on dom ready trigger the resize event.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var resizeflag = false;
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if ($("#wrapper").css("overflow") === "visible") {
            if(resizeflag == false){
                resizeflag = true;
                $("#wrapper").append('<div class="test">test</div>')
            }
        } else {
            if(resizeflag == true){
                resizeflag = false;
                $("#wrapper .test").remove();
            }
        }
    }).resize();
});
```

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cGWjP/1) & [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cGWjP/)

Comment: Hmm, I tried this but it's doing what my second example did -- all of my code starts looping when I resize the browser. For example, I'm using jquery to clone a div and append it to a mobile header, and it just keeps cloning/appending, cloning/appending all the way down the page everytime I move the browser width even a little bit.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yes, that worked. Thank you! So it seems I have to undo everything I do. Hopefully someday soon there will be a more efficient way to handle responsive jquery.